# Linking fails using mpicc on C++ program

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, mpi, flags

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit.  I have installed OpenMPI.  I'm trying to build the following code, which is a snippet from a test problem from the book "Using MPI" by Gropp/Lusk/Skjellum:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int size, rank;

    MPI::Init(argc, argv);

    size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
    rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

    MPI::Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

From a terminal, I can use the mpicc wrapper to retrieve the follow information that I need for compiling and linking on my machine:

```
$ mpicc --showme:compile
-I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -pthread
$ mpicc --showme:link
-pthread -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic -lnsl -lutil -lm -ldl
```

I can compile the code successfully.  However, the **linking fails**.  Here is my compiler and linker steps:

```
make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
mpicc -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/openmpi/include/openmpi -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -pthread -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: test
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
mpicc -L/usr/lib/openmpi/lib -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -o"test"  ./main.o   -lm -ldl -lmpi -lopen-rte -lopen-pal -lnsl -lutil
./main.o: In function `main':
/home/djunderw/ncsu/workspace/test/Debug/../main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `MPI::COMM_WORLD'
/home/djunderw/ncsu/workspace/test/Debug/../main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `MPI::COMM_WORLD'
./main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:72: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
.......
```

I used `.......` above to denote the fact that the error message go on and on--there are quite a few of them, but I don't think they're all necessary to show here.  If they are, please ask, and I'll paste them all.

**My suspicion is that my linker flags are not in the correct order.**  Another thread comes to that conclusion: [Link errors while using G++ for MPI code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451340/link-errors-while-using-g-for-mpi-code).  But if so, I can't figure out what is out of order.

**Why is my linking failing?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**SOLVED:**  I changed `mpicc` to `mpic++`, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Is your file a .c file or .cpp file. The question is mpicc is c compiler and mpic++ is c++ compiler, so if yours is a c program, compiling it with C++ compiler is not a recommendable I think.