# OpenMPI issues with arm64 architecture

Tags: c++, apple-m1, openmpi

I am trying to use the OpenMPI library for parallelizing a script. I am using an M1 Macbook Pro which has arm64 architecture. When I try to compile the following code with mpicc

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<vector>
#include<random>
#include<mpi.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    
    int size, rank;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    printf("Hello: rank %d, world: %d\n", rank, size);
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

I get **Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Please let me know how I can fix this issue, I am using OpenMPI version 4.1.4

Comment: And name of the symbol?

Comment: https://imgur.com/R9kvyNY
https://imgur.com/ie0RvSD
it's a long message, took 2 screenshots, first then second

Comment: You are probably compiling c++ code with c compiler. It seems, for c++ you should use [mpic++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13756312/4074081).

Comment: I concur with @dewaffled suggestion - you have C++ headers, then use C++ compiler: mpic++ or mpicxx. See https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps for details